# How can i copy an object in javascript correctly?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to copy an object in other using spread operator but wheni change one item from array in a copy object, the original is changed to. Any one knows how can i make the change only in object 2 ?

Follow a simple example:

```
let obj1 = { a:'hello', b:'hi', c: [1,2,3] }
let obj2 = { ...obj1 }
obj2.c[1] = 44
```

**EDIT:**
This thread has the answer :)
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common and secure method is through Object.assign():

```
let clone = Object.assign({}, myObj);
```

It creates a shallow copy, if you want a deep copy you can use lodash deepClone(), for example or write yourself a recursive cloner.

Comment: i tryed this, but still change the both two.

Comment: maybe you are doing it wrong, if you want a copy that's how you get it avoiding mutations so the error must be elsewhere.

Comment: It changes the original when you change the array property in the cloned object.... https://jsfiddle.net/oyL4hxwx/

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: There's no lodash tag in the question ???  Sorry, but this is just wrong.

Comment: ES6/ES7 does not have a deepClone, so you have to fallback on other tools or write a cloner by yourself

Comment: I tested with the example above, when I change an element that is not an array this works, but when I change the array keeps changing the two. one solution I thought was: 
 obj2.c = obj1.c.slice();

but i think thats not a god way to do this.

Comment: Read previous comment